# Existing tag [json-api] is shadowed by recently created synonym "json-api" of [json]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

Stack Overflow had a [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api) tag for the [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) since years. Between the years "json-api" was additionally added as a synonym to [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) tag. The synonym shadows the [json-api] tag, which still exists. It is not possible anymore to search for questions with the existing [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api) tag.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was added as a synonym. JSON is a serialisation format, there is no API for it. Is [tag:xml-api] a synonym to [tag:xml]? Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I agree, json-api should definitely not be a synonym of json

Comment: This is not even the same thing. JSON-api is about writing api's in json using a convetion. JSON is, like @VLAZ noted, a format without any convention.

Answer (score 4):

**I have removed the synonym.**

The synonym mapping [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api) to [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) was created on October 22nd by [sta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575350/sta). (Presumably, there were also some other users who voted to approve this tag synonym, or perhaps a single moderator, but that information is not accessible to me. I can only see the original creator.)

There are currently 616 questions with the tag [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api), which means that there were 616 questions with the [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api) tag before the synonym was put into place.

So far, the synonym's existence has caused the remapping of 5 questions that were originally tagged [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api) at the time of submission into [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json). What that means is that the extent of the "damage" is minor.

With the synonym removed, there are once again 616 questions with the tag [json-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-api), and new questions with that tag will no longer be mapped/converted into having the tag [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json).